# Is there a spell for carrying more weight in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

As far as remember, in Oblivion there is a spell for carrying more weight. Is there a similar spell in Skyrim?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34949/how-do-i-increase-the-maximum-amount-of-weight-my-character-can-carry-before-the

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no such spell in Skyrim.

You can carry more weight by:

- Wearing items with the Fortify Carry Weight enchantment
- Drinking a potion of Fortify Carry Weight
- Adding points to Stamina when you level up
- Giving some stuff to your hireling
- Climbing onto a horse
- Using The Steed Stone, allows you to carry +100.
- The Extra Pockets perk, which is part of the Pickpocket skill, also allows you to carry +100.

Comment: Technically, getting onto a horse doesn't allow you to carry more, it simply negates some of the consequences of being overburdened.  ;-)

Comment: A potion of Strength is another option, although it seems to do exactly the same thing as a potion of Fortify Carry Weight so I'm not sure why they both exist.

Comment: Don't forget the Steed Stone which can add 100 to your carry ability.

Comment: How does the horse thing work? You can always carry more than your maximum allowance, but then you can only walk slowly and cannot run. Do you mean that a horse won't care how loaded its passenger is?

Comment: @Bora: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @DaveSherohman So you can carry an infinite amount of weight, as long as you're on a horse? :/ Man, those horses are ignoring *all* the physics.

Answer (score 2):

In the vanilla game, no. With mods, yes:

- [Carry Weight Spells](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/4710)
- [Feather Spells](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/8538)
- [Ancient Spells - Morrowind and Oblivion Spells](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9153)

Note: In older TES games like [Morrowind](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Feather) and [Oblivion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Feather), the 'fortify carry weight' spell was named '[Feather](http://uesp.net/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=feather&button=Submit)'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a spell. However, there is a potion of fortify carry weight.

There are also items with fortify carry weight enchance.

If you disenchant that and you use restoration glitch and use OP fortify enchant, you can create an item with insane amount of carry weight.

[image]

There you go. You will never have to worry about weight again.

How to get that boot?

**Buy item with fortify carry weight. Go here.**

> It usually has names like: All varieties of Boots of Lifting All
> varieties of Boots of Hauling All varieties of Boots of Strength All
> varieties of Boots of Brawn All varieties of Boots of the Ox All
> varieties of Boots of the Mammoth
> https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fortify_Carry_Weight

**Disenchant**

So you can learn the enchanting

**Use fortify restoration glitch to create op fortify enchanting potion**

too long to explain here. https://www.google.com/search?q=skyrim+fortify+restoration+glitch&oq=skyrim+fortify+restoration+glitch

**Drink a 20k% -30k% fortify enchanting potion**

Too much and the game will crash. Too little and why bother?

You have 30 seconds to fortify your item with your fortify carry weight.

Comment: Drawback is that your inventory will start lagging significantly if there are a lot of items.

Comment: not sure what you mean. I am doing the glitch and it works very fine

Comment: I did this before as well, but when you have 5000+ items (non-stacked) in your inventory, the game doesn't handle opening the inventory that well.

Comment: Why do you have 5000 items? Put most unused item in a chest or something. Bring what you like

Comment: Hoarder syndrome :D. Loot every castle, cave, corpse and country.

Comment: Yea. Put most on chest in brisshome. In fact, there is a mod that link all chests or something. Just bring what you need